# How to use flask-login?

Tags: python, flask

I refer to the information in [Flask-Login github](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login)

Part of it is written like this,  `def user_loader(email)`, I see

```
user = User()
user.id = email
```

But in `User()` I can't find any about `id` and how to use this function on that example

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I just add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look it's very simple, in the 'example' they show there isn't. Is in fact a blank template.

By reporting what they have, in the same page you posted check for this:

```
class User(flask_login.UserMixin):
    pass
```

As you can see the user flask (with flask.login.UserMixin inherited) is empty, is filled with a pass. Normally you may fill it up as follow:

### EXAMPLE

```
class User(flask_login.UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(30))
    session_token = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
```

> **[Here](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/main/test_login.py)** do a CTRL + F and search for (class User(UserMixin):), here is what follows:

```
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, name, id, active=True):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.active = active
```

> > ### What does UserMixIn?

> [Here](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/main/flask_login/mixins.py) You can see how they implemented the UserMixin in which User() will inherit:

```
class UserMixin(object):
    '''
    This provides default implementations for the methods that Flask-Login
    expects user objects to have.
    '''

    if not PY2:  # pragma: no cover
        # Python 3 implicitly set __hash__ to None if we override __eq__
        # We set it back to its default implementation
        __hash__ = object.__hash__

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        try:
            return text_type(self.id)
        except AttributeError:
            raise NotImplementedError('No `id` attribute - override `get_id`')

    def __eq__(self, other):
        '''
        Checks the equality of two `UserMixin` objects using `get_id`.
        '''
        if isinstance(other, UserMixin):
            return self.get_id() == other.get_id()
        return NotImplemented

    def __ne__(self, other):
        '''
        Checks the inequality of two `UserMixin` objects using `get_id`.
        '''
        equal = self.__eq__(other)
        if equal is NotImplemented:
            return NotImplemented
        return not equal
```

- is_authenticated: a property that is True if the user has valid credentials or False otherwise.
- is_active: a property that is True if the user's account is active or False otherwise.
- is_anonymous: a property that is False for regular users, and True for a special, anonymous user.
- get_id(): a method that returns a unique identifier for the user as a string (unicode, if using Python 2).

> Usefull links:

- [Pretty Printed Tutorial(probably the best I suggest you to watch)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dEM-s3mRLE&list=PLXmMXHVSvS-CoYS177-UvMAQYRfL3fBtX&index=84)
- [Flask-Login DOCS](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask-login)
- [Source code for flask_login.mixins](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/flask_login/mixins.html)
- [Miguel GrinBerg Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins)
- [One SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59252203/i-am-trying-to-learn-flask-but-usermixin-seems-not-to-work)

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a lot but it feels complicated

Comment: It is ineed, not easy, look at this course https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dEM-s3mRLE&list=PLXmMXHVSvS-CoYS177-UvMAQYRfL3fBtX&index=84  is pretty printed, I also add it to the answer. this will help you a lot, I think go the basic first then go deep into their github repository